# Book about a girl with magic. Van and groupies and boy's name carved into her chest

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember that the book is about a girl who had magical abilities, but it's been so long that I don't fully remember it. There were some points in the book where the girl was kinda flying and no one could see her like she was a ghost, and something about a forest. There was a guy and a van, and some groupies — I think that's what they were — but I know that there was one girl that was cutting a guy's name into her chest and she was so happy about it or something, and I think there was a nighttime beach scene. I don't remember a lot because it was over four years ago that I read it.

Comment: I feel like the "carving the guy's name into her chest" should stick out as a plot point, and it actually sounds vaguely familiar. Did she do it in a body she was possessing?

Comment: im not to sure... theres a chance that im combining different books in my head lol.... but i dont think so.... such a shame that i cant remember any of the names of the characters

Comment: I don't suppose any new details have come to you?